# Transparent PNG in NSView, Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a project with a transparent PNG file under my resources, available at runtime. I'd like to load it up when my view is created and project it, while keeping its transparency onto the NSView instance I have.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSImage.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/)

Answer (score 1):

Use some of the methods drawn... and, in operation: use the number 5 -> [NSCompositeSourceAtop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ;)